# ¿Como ejecutar un Script en Windows 7 sin confirmacion?

Tags: java, windows, cmd, powershell

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en el que necesito ejecutar un Script en windows 7. Usé **Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted** en el Power Shell para habilitar la ejecucion de Script, pero al intentar ejecutarlo, siempre sale el cmd y pide confirmacion. Lo que necesito es saber como ejecutarlo directamente sin pedir esta confirmacion, porque la idea es ejecutarlo muchas veces en java, y si pide confirmacion, el proyecto muestra error debido a que no pudo ejecutarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeramente la flag de `Unrestricted` segun Microsoft *"Carga todos los archivos de configuración y ejecuta  todos los scripts".* Pero si es  un script sin firmar que se descargo de Internet, se pedirá permisos antes de  ejecutarlo. Entonces esta técnica no da como resultado un cambio de configuración o requiere la escritura en el disco.

Podrias usar la flag "Bypass" que dice: `"Nada está bloqueado y no hay advertencias ni mensajes"`

```
PS C:\> Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .script.ps1
```

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es que no hayan restricciones para ningún script puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Scope LocalMachine
```

Debes tener en cuenta que es la forma menos recomendada pues esto abre una brecha de seguridad en la que confias en todos los scripts que estan en tu computadora.

Para ejecutar los scripts posteriormente solo no necesitas más que:

```
.\ScriptAEjecutar.ps1
javac Miprograma.java
java MiPrograma
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.